# Dimension of Secant variety of an irreducible projective curve not contained in a plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to show that this dimension is three, but I'm stuck. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: It's great to know that your curve is not contained in a plane, but *where* exactly is it? And what does *curve* mean, by the way?

Comment: @georges It is exercise $11.25$ in Harris's algebraic geometry book:"Show that if $X\subset\mathbb{P}^{n}$ is an irreducible curve then its chordal variety $S(X)$ is three-dimensional unless $X$ is contained in a plane."

Comment: @Gauloises Doesn't it follow from Proposition 11.24, which says $\operatorname{dim} S(X) \le 3$? You only have to show that if $X$ is contained in a plane, then for a general point $p \in \overline{qr}$ lying on a secant line to $X$ lies on an infinite finite number of secant lines to $X$. If $X$ is linear, then $\operatorname{dim} S(X) = 1$ trivially. If not, then should be infinitely many points on $X \setminus \overline{qr}$ that determine distinct secant lines through $r$.